# $x^4-2x^3+mx^2-2x+1=0$, $m \in R$, $x_1=x_2 \in R-\{-1\}$

Tags: polynomials, roots, parametric

### Given the equation: $x^4-2x^3+mx^2-2x+1=0$, $m \in R$

To which interval does $m$ belong, so that the equation has $x_1=x_2 \in \mathbb R\setminus\{-1\}$, provided that $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are the roots of the equation.

### Since I got this from Vieta's:

$$2x_1+x_3+x_4=2$$
$$x_1^2+2x_1x_3+2x_1x_4+x_3x_4=m$$
$$x_1^2x_3x_4=1$$
$$x_1^2x_3+x_1^2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_1x_3x_4=2$$

### I figured I could do this:

$$x_1^2(x_3+x_4)+2x_1x_3x_4=2$$
$$x_3+x_4=2-2x_1$$
$$x_1x_3x_4= \frac{1}{x_1}$$
$$x_1^2(2-2x_1)+\frac{2}{x_1}=2$$
$$2x_1^4-2x_1^3+2x_1-2=0$$

So I use Horner's on the last line above and get $x_ 1=1$ the only real root which is also $x_2$.

Thus I am able to find $m=2$ which belongs to the interval of the correct answer[which is $(1, \infty )$].

The thing is I am not sure this is the only $m$ that provides a solution to the exercise... Is it the only value of $m$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint: since $$x=0$$ is not a solution then write your equation in the form
$$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}-2\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)+m=0$$ now set $$x+\frac{1}{x}=t$$ and you will get a quadratic equation in $t$

Comment: And what is the rest?

Comment: I got $t=1 \pm \sqrt{3-m}$ and by solving for $t=x+ \frac{1}{x}$ I got $m=\{2,-6\} $. Can't seem to figure out why $m=-6$ is not a good solution though(which is not, according to the answer sheet).

Comment: @Alexander For these two values of $t$ you'll get two equations. There are also cases, when one of roots of the first equation is equal to one of roots of the second equation. See my solution. It's much more short.

Comment: if $m=-6$ we get $$\left( {x}^{2}-4\,x+1 \right)  \left( x+1 \right) ^{2}$$

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner In your way there are more cases. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

We can get your result also by the following way.
$$(x^4-2x^3+mx^2-2x+1)'=0$$ or
$$4x^3-6x^2+2mx-2=0$$ or
$$2x^4-3x^3+mx^2-x=0$$ or
$$mx^2=-2x^4+3x^3+x,$$ which gives
$$x^4-2x^3+(-2x^4+3x^3+x)-2x+1=0$$ or
$$x^4-x^3+x-1=0$$ or
$$(x^3+1)(x-1)=0,$$
which gives $x=1$ and $m=2$.

Comment: How do you get the $m=2$?

Comment: @Alexander I just substituted $x=1$ in the original equation. Because now I  know that $x_1=x_2=1$ only.